# Flushing right the pagebackrefs in the bibliography with hyperref

Tags: horizontal-alignment, bibliographies, hyperref, back-referencing

I'd like to flush the back references to pages in my bibliography to the right. I have a solution for the `citeref` package, see the MWE. But how can I achieve this when using `hyperref`?

```
\documentclass{article}

%% This works fine:
\usepackage{citeref}
\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{citeref}{
\def\bibitempages#1{\newblock \hglue\fill\mbox{[#1]}}}
\makeatother

%% But how to flush the pagerefs right with hyperref?
% \usepackage[pagebackref]{hyperref}


\begin{document}

Citing~\cite{Test2013}.

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\begin{thebibliography}{TT13}

  \bibitem[TT13]{Test2013}
  Test, Arthur, and Test, Betsy.
  \newblock \emph{Some obscure ramblings}.
  \newblock Nature
  \textbf{1}: 1--13, 2013

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the `backref` package provides any hooks, so you have to patch it, but I think this does what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pagebackref]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\let\oldBR@backref=\BR@backref
\renewcommand{\BR@backref}{\hfill\oldBR@backref}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Citing~\cite{Test2013}.

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\begin{thebibliography}{TT13}

  \bibitem[TT13]{Test2013}
  Test, Arthur, and Test, Betsy.
  \newblock \emph{Some obscure ramblings}.
  \newblock Nature
  \textbf{1}: 1--13, 2013

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```